# Coffeescript class shares properties

Tags: coffeescript

I've detected a very weird behavior in coffeescript.

```
class Foo
    list: []
    add: (val)->
        @list.push(val)


x = new Foo()
x.add(1)
console.log(x.list.length) // 1

y = new Foo()
y.add(1)
console.log(y.list.length) // 2
```

So as you see the @list property got shared between the two class instances in a strange way.
I've never faced similar issue before, in coffeescript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert it to JavaScript:

```
var Foo, x, y;

Foo = (function() {
  function Foo() {}

  Foo.prototype.list = [];

  Foo.prototype.add = function(val) {
    return this.list.push(val);
  };

  return Foo;

})();
```

As you can see, `Foo.prototype.list` is a property of the *prototype*, not of an instance of your class. There's only one array and it will be shared across all of the instances of your class.

To make `list` an instance variable, add it to the constructor:

```
class Foo
    constructor: ->
        @list = []

    add: (val)->
        @list.push(val)
```